# Are there programs to program Assembly in?

Tags: assembly

I have a lot of downtime at school and want to teach myself Assembly, but Command Prompt is blocked on my school laptop. Is there some way I could get around this or some programs that simulate programming in Assembly? My computer uses an Intel Centium processor.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of times you open IE and type **C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe** in the address bar. If your school has not been thorough , you can launch a command window with it.

If not you can try an

1. [online assembly simulator](http://labs.kitiyo.com/8085/free-online-assember-simulator-8085.html)
2. [Assembler IDE/Simulator for beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27568/assembler-ide-simulator-for-beginner)

Comment: I think you can probably create a batch file that launches cmd.exe.  That's what I did in high school at least. :P

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://bellard.org/jslinux/ (hope your school-issued laptop has a good browser, though)

See here for tech notes: http://bellard.org/jslinux/tech.html

I assume if you want to learn Assembly you can figure out how to get there given a Linux prompt :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more specific about what kind of assembly you want to learn.

This site offers a NASM and GCC simulator that you can run in the browser
[IDE One](http://ideone.com/)

I believe MASM has a simulator as well, and can be found in an easy google search.

Another option is ARM, which has an IDE by Keil called uVision, which is a free download.
[uVision](http://www.keil.com/arm/mdk.asp)

There are plenty of different assembly languages..

Answer (score 0):

I would be curious to hear about your experience using an instruction set and assembly tutorial I put together:

https://github.com/dwelch67/lsasim

I designed the instruction set around common and clean concepts from various processors.  The tutorial is in the form of: just type this code and run it, then I will tell you what it did.

I strongly discourage x86 as your first assembly language.  Try lsasim or msp430 or ARM/thumb or other much better, much cleaner, much more understandable instruction sets, then once you have a little experience with one or a few (msp430, arm, thumb for example) try going to x86.  I have simulators for almost everything I am talking about at github.com/dwelch67.  No tutorials though.  I have a thumb simulator, a subset of the arm instruction set, an msp430 simulator, and I borrowed and stripped down an 8088/8806 instruction set simulator as I believe that if you go with x86 you should start with the basics.  I feel it will make what you see in todays x86 architecture more understandable.

I also feel the simulator approach gives you better visibility into what is going on, and you dont crash or trash your system by trying to learn on it while also using it.

Although, spim is often used to teach asm in school I would also avoid mips as a first instruction set.  It is not a bad instruction set the problem lies in the attitude and approach that the documentation takes.  It was specifically architected for speed for a specific period of history in computing.  Hardware performance at the sake of punishing the programmer, it has a few non-common approaches to things.  I would again recommend going with something middle ground and orthogonal like the ones I mentioned above.

Once you learn one or two of these clean instruction sets then picking up a new instruction set is a matter of syntax.  significantly easier than trying to learn a new programming language.  Each instruction set you learn makes the next one that much easier.  Before long you could be coding in a matter of minutes if you have some examples of the new-to-you instruction set.  In particular if you have a compiler (C, etc) that you can disassemble the output, look those instructions up in the reference material and off you go...